# Angular2 WebApi -- Pre-flight calling controller, PUTfails

Tags: angular, cors

New to Angular and Webapi on .netCore.  I am having a weird scenario, or maybe I don't understand preflight/CORS well enough. It appears my preflight for a PUT calls my controller method and executes it.  I set a breakpoint in controller put method and check .net tab.  Pre-flight is only displayed.  But looking at the response, it returns a 204 no content.

Looking at the .net tab in firebug, the PUT failed for CORS and ends up in error handler in angular2.   Verifying results, the webapi PUT method saved everything corretly.

I think I need to catch the pre-flight options request and send a 200 response.  But not sure how in .netCORE.  I am confused on what is happening and why. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cors is enabled in startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder();
        corsBuilder.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials();
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", corsBuilder.Build());
        });
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        -
        -
```

}

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
       app.UseCors("AllowAll");

       app.UseMvc();

       -
       -
   }
```

[Request and Response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib8dN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in my action result.

return Ok();   is what I should of been returning.

I was returning a CreatedAtRoute, not sure why that was showing as a Cors error in the network tab